# Getting null whenever trying to collect data from SharedFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

I have a SharedFlow in ViewModel, where I make a call to repository, to retrieve from the database a single record by some id. This is will be set whenever user will click on some record in RecyclerView. The problem is I constantly getting null, but if I hardcode id in repository parameter, then everything works fine.

DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id = :id")
fun getEmployeeById(id: Int?): Flow<EmployeeModel>
```

RepositoryInterface

```
fun getEmployeeById(id: Int?): Flow<EmployeeModel>
```

RepositoryImplementation

```
    override fun getEmployeeById(id: Int?): Flow<EmployeeModel> {
    return employeeDAO.getEmployeeById(id)
}
```

ViewModel

```
var employeeById: SharedFlow<DatabaseState<EmployeeModel>> = repository.get().getEmployeeById(employeeId.value?.toInt())
    .map {
        println("onCreateView in VM. ID ${employeeId.value}  |  data: $it")
        DatabaseState.Success(it) }
    .catch { DatabaseState.Error(it.message) }
    .shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), replay = 0)
```

Fragment

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
           mViewModel.employeeById.collect{ employee ->
               when (employee){
                   is DatabaseState.Success -> {
                       Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView APDEJCIK: ${mViewModel.employeeId.value} | ${employee.data}")
                   }
                   is DatabaseState.Error -> {
                       Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView: Failed to retrieve data about employee in UpdateFragmentEmployee fragment")}
               }
           }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I'm loging the ID from the ViewModel a couple of times, and it every times has correct id to the position I've clicked, so the ID should be ok.

Edit:
Model class

```
    @Entity(tableName = "employees")
data class EmployeeModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "surname")
    val surname: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "age")
    val age: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "workplace")
    val workplace: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "salary")
    val salary: Double
)
```

Comment: Your Flow is non-nullable. What do you mean by "getting null"? It doesn't make sense that `id` is a nullable parameter but your Flow type is not a list, unless you are somehow guaranteeing there is exactly one row in the database where this id is null. Usually an "ID" is never null anyway.

Comment: Whenever I log data in ViewModel, or Fragment, I just get null. You can see these logs in question. I want to get single object of employee (his name, surname etc). That's why I did not used List.

Comment: So the log says `"onCreateView in VM. ID <some id>  |  data: null"` ? This doesn't seem like it should be possible since the flow's type is non-nullable.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have no idea why, but it does. I mean, I can send a screenshot, but it's not necessary I guess

Comment: I've find something. Whenever I'll try to log inside of .map any property of object, like name, or something, I getting this error VM ERROR Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.employeemanagement.Model.EmployeeModel.getName()' on a null object reference

Comment: Can you show me your `EmployeeModel`

Comment: @fshdn19 it is in the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these code below have a problem

```
var employeeById: SharedFlow<DatabaseState<EmployeeModel>> = repository.get().getEmployeeById(employeeId.value?.toInt())
.map {
    println("onCreateView in VM. ID ${employeeId.value}  |  data: $it")
    DatabaseState.Success(it) }
.catch { DatabaseState.Error(it.message) }
.shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), replay = 0)
```

Because of this declaration, your `employeeById` will be created when your view model is created, so `employeeId.value` is still null.
Then, because of `SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed()`. the map function will only get called when your flow has a subscriber on your `repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)`. At this time, your `employeeId.value` is set the correct value. This is why you get a very weird log.

To fix your issue, I think some things need to be changed.

Your DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id = :id")
fun getEmployeeById(id: Int): Flow<EmployeeModel?>
```

Your viewModel. I assume that you have a state flow for your employee. You should use `flatMap` to update your employeeById value whenever your employee changes.

```
val employeeById: SharedFlow<DatabaseState<EmployeeModel>> = employeeId.filterNotNull().flatMapLatest {
   repository.get().getEmployeeById(it.toInt())
}.map {
    if (it!= null) DatabaseState.Success(it) else DatabaseState.Error("NOT FOUND")
}.catch { DatabaseState.Error(it.message) }
.shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), replay = 0)
```

Last thing, if you use `employeeById` to display data. Consider using `StateFlow` instead of `SharedFlow`

Comment: I'm using MutableLiveData to "update" the id of an employee. Unfortunately, I can't use this line:  employeeId.filterNotNull().flatMapLatest.  I'll be using this SharedFlow to display it, and push changed data do the database.

Comment: Change your live data to state flow please